# Sorting list of lists by the first element of each sub-list

Tags: python

How to sort a list of lists according to the first element of each list?

For example, giving this unsorted list:

```
[[1,4,7],[3,6,9],[2,59,8]]
```

The sorted result should be:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,59,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Plain and simple use `sorted(d)`?

Answer (score 77):

Use sorted function along with passing anonymous function as value to the key argument. `key=lambda x: x[0]` will do sorting according to the first element in each sublist.

```
>>> lis = [[1,4,7],[3,6,9],[2,59,8]]
>>> sorted(lis, key=lambda x: x[0])
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 59, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: You should avoid using `l` as variable name, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).

Comment: @AvinashRaj what if you want to sort in descending order?

Comment: @NitishKumarPal You can reverse the result of sorting the list.`sorted(lis, key=lambda x: x[0])[::-1]`

Comment: @NitishKumarPal or you can also do: `sorted(lis, key=lambda x: -x[0])`

Comment: `sorted(lis, key=lambda x: -x[0])` is ok to sort-reverse numeric elements but will fail for strings, so if needed use @rAntonioH `sorted(lis, key=lambda x: x[0])[::-1]`

Answer (score 33):

If you're sorting by first element of nested list, you can simply use `list.sort()` method.

```
>>> lis = [[1,4,7],[3,6,9],[2,59,8]]
>>> lis.sort()
>>> lis
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 59, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

If you want to do a reverse sort, you can use `lis.reverse()` after `lis.sort()`

```
>>> lis.reverse()
>>> lis
[[3, 6, 9], [2, 59, 8], [1, 4, 7]]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
li = [[1,4,7],[3,6,9],[2,59,8]]
li.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

This will sort in place changing the original list though. If you want to keep the original list, it is better to use:

```
sorted(li, key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Comment: it's `li` not `l1` I think there's a typo

Comment: What's the point of casting to Int if the list is already all ints?