# Sorting sub-lists in a list alphabetically

Tags: python, list

I am trying to order sub-lists in a list alphabetically and have seen that `.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955553/sorting-list-of-lists-by-the-first-element-of-each-sub-list). Here is my list:

```
lis = [['. Michels',
        'Lorenzo Petroli',
        'Carlos Arthur Lang Lisba',
        'Fernanda Gusmo de Lima Kastensmidt',
        'Luigi Carro'],
       ['. Snchez', 'M. Rincn'],
       ['A-Nasser Ansari', 'Mohamed Abdel-Mottaleb']]
```

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

I now call `lis` and it appears as if nothing has happened to the first entry:

```
[['. Michels',
  'Lorenzo Petroli',
  'Carlos Arthur Lang Lisba',
  'Fernanda Gusmo de Lima Kastensmidt',
  'Luigi Carro'],
 ['. Snchez', 'M. Rincn'],
 ['A-Nasser Ansari', 'Mohamed Abdel-Mottaleb']]
```

which should be

```
['. Michels',
 'Carlos Arthur Lang Lisba',
 'Fernanda Gusmo de Lima Kastensmidt',
 'Lorenzo Petroli',
 'Luigi Carro'
 ]
```

right?

Comment: you have to sort every _sublist_ your current implementation only looks at the outer most list, perhaps a loop can solve your issue? you should notice the difference between the linked question and your issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
for e in lis:
  e.sort()
```

This will sort all elements of your outer list (i. e. each inner list) in-place.

If you need sorted copies, have a look at @Mykola Zotko's answer.  Sorting in-place is cheaper, though.

Your approach did this instead:  Sort the outer list by the first elements of the inner lists.  Unfortunately based on the first elements, the outer list was already sorted (`'. Michels' < '. Snchez' < 'A-Nasser Ansari'` because the `'.'` is before all letters in the ASCII code).  So nothing was changed by your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the function `sorted()` to each sublist in the list:

```
list(map(sorted, lis))
```

Answer (score 1):

you have list of the list, so simple solution is:

```
lis = [['. Michels',
        'Lorenzo Petroli',
        'Carlos Arthur Lang Lisba',
        'Fernanda Gusmo de Lima Kastensmidt',
        'Luigi Carro'],
       ['. Snchez', 'M. Rincn'],
       ['A-Nasser Ansari', 'Mohamed Abdel-Mottaleb']]
[sorted(x) for x in lis]
```

and the result you will have:

```
[['. Michels',
  'Carlos Arthur Lang Lisba',
  'Fernanda Gusmo de Lima Kastensmidt',
  'Lorenzo Petroli',
  'Luigi Carro'],
 ['. Snchez', 'M. Rincn'],
 ['A-Nasser Ansari', 'Mohamed Abdel-Mottaleb']]
```

or if you need to sort by some condition you can use the sorted with `key`, example (will give the same result as first solution):

```
[sorted(x, key=lambda x:x[0]) for x in lis]
```