# Python sorting arrays by element contained?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm looking to take a list of lists and sort them by an element contained in the contained lists. For clarification, I want to have a list like this code

```
myList = []
myList.append([1, 2, 3])
myList.append([1, 1, 1])
myList.append([1, 3, 2])
```

and then sort the elements of list by the last element of each contained list and it would end up looking like this

```
           |
myList = ( v
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 3, 2],
    [1, 1, 1])
```

I also have the numpy library imported in this project. I was looking at argsort for numpy but I don't think you can sort it along an axis of an element

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name because it's built into python.

Comment: Does this need to be time and space efficient or are there not many items in this list?

Comment: I will be having a few hundred thousand items in the lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting list of lists by the first element of each sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955553/sorting-list-of-lists-by-the-first-element-of-each-sub-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use `list` as variable name as it is one of python built-in function, and second you can use `sorted` function to sort by position

```
l = []
l.append([1, 2, 3])
l.append([1, 1, 1])
l.append([1, 3, 2])
sorted(l,key = lambda x : x[2])
#[[1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `lambda x : x[-1]` will be more general to pick last element

Comment: `l` (el) isn't a good variable name.  It looks like a '1' (one) in many fonts.  Can use the `operator` library: `my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(-1))`