# Python - List of lists, Get the list with the biggest number as the first value

Tags: python, list, sorting

I got a list of lists like the one below

```
l = [
    [1, ....],
    [2, ....],
    [3, ....],
]
```

And I want as a result the list with the bigger number as the first element.

So the result of the above list should be:

```
[3, ....],
```

If we get multiple times the highest number, just get one of them in random

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list of lists by the first element of each sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955553/sorting-list-of-lists-by-the-first-element-of-each-sub-list)

Comment: you can pass a key arg on sorted inbuilt method; ```sorted(my_cool_list, key=lambda my_list: my_list[0])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
new_l = sorted(l,key=lambda x : x[0],reverse=True)
```

If you want only first sorted list

```
new_l[0]
```