# Python pandas sort_values() with nested list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort a nested dict in pyhon via pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd 

# Data structure (nested list):
# {
#   category_name: [[rank, id], ...],
#   ...
# }

all_categories = {
    "category_name1": [[2, 12345], [1, 32512], [3, 32382]],
    "category_name2": [[3, 12345], [9, 25318], [1, 24623]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(all_categories.items(), columns=['Category', 'Rank'])
df.sort_values(['Rank'], ascending=True, inplace=True) # this only sorts the list of lists
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get to my goal? I can't figure it out. Via panda it's possible to `sort_values()` by the second column, but I can't figure out how to sort the nested dict/list.

I want to sort ascending by the rank, not the id.

Comment: You need to show us some sample data

Comment: `all_categories['Rank'][i][rank]` this part confuse me ???

Comment: I changed it, I see why you are confused. I meant to sort by the rank, not the id. Based on the data structure sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest option is to apply `sort()` (note that the sorting occurs in place, so don't assign back to `df.Rank` in this case):

```
df.Rank.apply(list.sort)
```

Or apply `sorted()` with a [custom key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955637/13138364) and assign back to `df.Rank`:

```
df.Rank = df.Rank.apply(lambda row: sorted(row, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Output in either case:

```
>>> df
         Category                                  Rank
0  category_name1  [[1, 32512], [2, 12345], [3, 32382]]
1  category_name2  [[1, 24623], [3, 12345], [9, 25318]]
```

---

This is the [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) of `sort()` vs `sorted()` vs `explode()`:

[image: timing results]

```
import perfplot

def explode(df):
    df = df.explode('Rank')
    df['rank_num'] = df.Rank.str[0]
    df = df.sort_values(['Category', 'rank_num']).groupby('Category', as_index=False).agg(list)
    return df

def apply_sort(df):
    df.Rank.apply(list.sort)
    return df

def apply_sorted(df):
    df.Rank = df.Rank.apply(lambda row: sorted(row, key=lambda x: x[0]))
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([df] * n),
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
    kernels=[explode, apply_sort, apply_sorted],
    equality_check=None,
)
```

---

To filter rows by list length, mask the rows with [**`str.len()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and `loc[]`:

```
mask = df.Rank.str.len().ge(10)
df.loc[mask, 'Rank'].apply(list.sort)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the insights and the perfplot. I'm just curious: you know how to ignore all `Rank` entrys with less then `N=10` entries.

Comment: @Patrick you're welcome. to filter lists by length, you can mask those rows with `str.len()` and `loc[]` (answer updated)

Comment: Thank you again, but the code doesn't count or show only entries with `n>10`, it's the same output from before. I mean the `len(all_categories['Rank']) > 10`

Comment: @Patrick correct, the current code just limits the sorting to the masked rows but still retains all the rows. if you want those other rows to be removed, you can do something like this instead: `df = df.loc[mask]; df.Rank.apply(list.sort)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_categories.items(), columns=['Category', 'Rank']).explode('Rank')
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x))

df = df.groupby('Category').agg(list).reset_index()
```

to dict

```
dict(df.agg(list, axis=1).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_categories.items(), columns=['Category', 'Rank'])
df.set_index('Rank', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_categories.items(), columns=['Category', 'Rank'])
df = df.set_index('Rank').sort_index().reset_index()
```

Comment: It's not working, same result as above, if I sort the list of lists. It's not even sorted by `id`

Answer (score 0):

It is much more efficient to use `df.explode` and then sort the values. It will be vectorized.

```
df = df.explode('Rank')
df['rank_num'] = df.Rank.str[0]

df.sort_values(['Category', 'rank_num'])
  .groupby('Category', as_index=False)
  .agg(list)
```

Output

```
         Category                                  Rank   rank_num
0  category_name1  [[1, 32512], [2, 12345], [3, 32382]]  [1, 2, 3]
1  category_name2  [[1, 24623], [3, 12345], [9, 25318]]  [1, 3, 9]
```

Comment: i did some timings and `explode` seems to be slower than `apply` in this case (i guess because `explode` still requires `groupby`+`agg`)