# Order nested lists inside column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, nested-lists

I have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Rachel', 'Adam','Joe'],
                   'Age':[95, 102, 31,np.nan],
                   'Scores':[np.nan, [80, 82, 78], [25, 20, 30, 60, 21],np.nan]
                  })
```

I would like to sort values inside column 'scores'.

Desired output:

```
 Name    Age     Scores
John    95.0     NaN
Rachel  102.0    [78,80,82]
Adam    31.0     [20,21,25,30,60]
Joe     NaN      NaN
```

I have tried the solutions from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959535/python-pandas-sort-values-with-nested-list), as well as the code

```
df.sort_values(by=["Scores"], na_position="first")
```

but result wasn not the deisred one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the null values then `map` with `sorted`

```
df['Scores'] = df['Scores'].dropna().map(sorted)
```

---

```
     Name    Age                Scores
0    John   95.0                   NaN
1  Rachel  102.0          [78, 80, 82]
2    Adam   31.0  [20, 21, 25, 30, 60]
3     Joe    NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: I hesitated to put this alternative, it looks fancier but is actually slower than a list comprehension (`map` is a loop) and won't work if there are duplicated indices (try on the input with `index=[1, 1, 2, 3]` or `index=[0, 1, 1, 2]`).

Comment: well, good to know

Answer (score 1):

As you have objects in your column, you need to loop:

```
df['Scores'] = [sorted(l) if isinstance(l, list) else l for l in df['Scores']]
```

Output:

```
     Name    Age                Scores
0    John   95.0                   NaN
1  Rachel  102.0          [78, 80, 82]
2    Adam   31.0  [20, 21, 25, 30, 60]
3     Joe    NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: the code runs, but resulting lists inside real-world dataset remain unordered [4, 18, 23, 11, 26, 8, 14, 1, 30, 2, 17, 25, ... any alternative?

Comment: @josepmaria have you assigned the output? Doesn't really make sense, can you provide a reproducible input that does that?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

One method is to conditionally sort the list by iterating over each row using  apply lambda, as follows:

```
df['Scores'] = df['Scores'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)

#   Name    Age Scores
#0  John    95.0    NaN
#1  Rachel  102.0   [78, 80, 82]
#2  Adam    31.0    [20, 21, 25, 30, 60]
#3  Joe     NaN     NaN
```

This also handles the missing values, which would present an issue in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Rachel', 'Adam', 'Joe'],
                   'Age': [95, 102, 31, np.nan],
                   'Scores': [np.nan, [80, 82, 78], [25, 20, 30, 60, 21], np.nan]})

def sort_scores(scores):
    if isinstance(scores, list):
        return np.sort(scores)
    else:
        return scores

df['Scores'] = df['Scores'].apply(sort_scores)

print(df)
"""    Name    Age                Scores
0    John   95.0                   NaN
1  Rachel  102.0          [78, 80, 82]
2    Adam   31.0  [20, 21, 25, 30, 60]
3     Joe    NaN                   NaN"""
```