# Rearrange sublists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` containing many sublists. I want to reorganize this list based on the first element of each sublist i.e. in ascending order. I present the current and expected output.

```
A=[[27, 31, 32, 36], [30, 34, 35, 39], [28, 32, 33, 37], [29, 33, 34, 38]]
C=[]


for i in range(0,len(A)):
    B=A[i][0]
    C.append(B)
    C.sort()
    print(C)
```

The current output is

```
[27, 28, 29, 30]
```

The expected output is

```
[[27, 31, 32, 36], [28, 32, 33, 37], , [29, 33, 34, 38], [30, 34, 35, 39]]
```

Comment: `C = sorted(A)`?

Comment: try `A.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: It's not though. The output is `[27]`, followed by `[27, 30]`, etc.  And that makes sense because you are adding `A[i][0]` to `B`. And `A[i]` is the i-th list in A (like `[27, 31, 32, 36]` for `i == 0`) and with `[0]` you  are adding only the first element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list of lists by the first element of each sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955553/sorting-list-of-lists-by-the-first-element-of-each-sub-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to the `sorted` function, and the `lambda` keyword to create an anonymous function which returns the first element of a list.

```
>>> A=[[27, 31, 32, 36], [30, 34, 35, 39], [28, 32, 33, 37], [29, 33, 34, 38]]
>>> sorted(A, key = lambda iterable: iterable[0])
    [[27, 31, 32, 36], [28, 32, 33, 37], [29, 33, 34, 38], [30, 34, 35, 39]]
```

For sorting by the first element only, `sorted` does this by default, and so just `sorted(A)` will do the trick. The method presented above works for all indices.

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to use `sorted` coupled with a lambda function as the key:

```
C = sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
```